# Ajax on success of another ajax doesn't work in ie

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, jquery

I do an ajax call to get a list of all elements, say Products and populate them in a table with checkboxes. Then I make another ajax call to get which products were already selected and select them. This works in all browsers except ie. Am I doing something wrong?

```
$.ajax({
                url : "${product_category_url}",
                data : {"orgID":"${globalOrganisation.id}"},
                dataType : "html",
                statusCode: {
                    401: function() {
                        $('.ui-tabs-panel:visible').html("${ajax_session_expired}");
                    }
              },
              success : function(data) {
                  $("#productCategoryContainer").html(data);
                  $.ajax({
                      url: "${get_taggedProd_url}",
                      data: {"questionnaireId":_questionnaireId},
                      dataType: "json",
                      success: function(data){
                          var productIds = data.products;
                          $.each(productIds,function(index,value){
                             var obj = $('input[name="'+value+'"]');
                             obj[0].checked = true
                             selectRow(obj[0]);
                          });
                      }
                  });
              }
            });
```

Comment: check the console, check your syntax, check if the server returns anything, check if you have the correct url (IE has issue with paths sometimes, especially when the framework uses routing)

Comment: instead of making the next ajax calls to recheck the boxes, can't you store the values on client side and then just loop through them? Saves bandwidth and will definitely speed the process too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to caching by IE.

Please try this

```
$.ajax({
                url : "${product_category_url}",
                data : {"orgID":"${globalOrganisation.id}"},
                dataType : "html",
                statusCode: {
                    401: function() {
                        $('.ui-tabs-panel:visible').html("${ajax_session_expired}");
                    }
              },
              success : function(data) {
                  $("#productCategoryContainer").html(data);
                    $.ajaxSetup ({
    // Disable caching of AJAX responses
    cache: false
});

                  $.ajax({
                      url: "${get_taggedProd_url}",
                      data: {"questionnaireId":_questionnaireId},
                      dataType: "json",
                      success: function(data){
                          var productIds = data.products;
                          $.each(productIds,function(index,value){
                             var obj = $('input[name="'+value+'"]');
                             obj[0].checked = true
                             selectRow(obj[0]);
                          });
                      }
                  });
              }
            });
```

and if you need more details please look into   [this](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2008/12/ajax-cache-problem-in-ie.html)

Comment: I added  $.ajaxSetup ({
    // Disable caching of AJAX responses
    cache: false
});
after first success or you can add $.ajax({
       url: url,
       data: inputs + '&time=' + new Date(),
    )};
in first ajax this is also working.

Answer (score 0):

The thing in this code that always screws me up is trying to get the check box selected. Make sure `obj[0].checked = true` actually works.